# Can we use switch case in Netezza sql?

Tags: switch-statement, netezza

Can we use Switch case statement in Netezza script? If yes, what is the syntax? Is it similar to the switch case syntax in other languages?

Thanks,
Ammu

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See the [PureData documentation on case](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_case.html).